# Unable to upgrade git-client plugin in jenkins

Tags: jenkins

[image]

It appears I am unable to fix this situation.  It seems jenkins thinks I should have a newer version of a git plugin, one that is not out yet.  I do not see an option to upgrade.

Any idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

The first thing to check is your Jenkins version itself.

Try and upgrade Jenkins ([`war-stable/latest/jenkins.war`](http://mirrors.jenkins-ci.org/war-stable/latest/jenkins.war)) to see if the core client allows for those dependencies to be resolved.